# Upgrade to Angular 6, HostListener is not capturing events raised from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working on an asp.net mvc web application. On clicking a link, particular javascript module gets fired which creates a custom event and dispatches it to Angular 4 where the event gets captured using HostListener and further processing takes place.

**Javascript**

```
var evt = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
evt.initCustomEvent('UserEvent', null, null, params);
window.dispatchEvent(event);
```

**Angular 6**

```
@HostListener('UserEvent', ['$event'])
```

After upgrading to Angular 6 this functionality stopped working. The events are not getting captured by Angular 6.

I am new to Angular, so do not have much knowledge to go deep in to finding the issue.

Could any of you please assist?

Comment: Please you create a stackblitz for this.

Comment: I don't know, perhafs You must use ngZone. some like @ HotListener('UserEvent',['$event']onevent(arg){
   zone.run(()=>{....});
 }